# Stata tempfile not found when using append, save, use

Tags: macos, append, stata, temporary-files

I have a short do-file in Stata that uses a loop to read in some datasets, one at a time, and append them to a tempfile. However, this tempfile is not found when trying to open it at the end.

Running this script on Windows and MacOS (Stata 17):

```
clear
set more off
set trace on

local patha "<patha>"
local pathb "<pathb>"

use "`pathb'fileb.dta", clear

levelsof pathb_variable, local(l)

tempfile append_file

foreach i of local l {
    capture confirm file "`patha'filea_`i'.dta"
    if _rc==0 {  
        capture append using `append_file'
        save `append_file', replace
    }
    
}
use `append_file', clear
```

As `set trace` is on, I can see that the first line that runs in Stata, before `clear` and `set more off` is:

`do "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\10\STD7578_000000.tmp"` on Windows, and

`do "/var/folders/02/50xtwnrn5yb_wrh_md7s23br0000gn/T//SD26113.000000"` on Mac.

The error message that appears, just after `` use `append_file', clear `` is run, is:

`file C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\10\ST_7578_000001.tmp not found` on Windows, and

`file /var/folders/02/50xtwnrn5yb_wrh_md7s23br0000gn/T//S_26113.000001 not found` on Mac.

In both cases, it looks like a different tempfile being created than is being accessed? The tempfile filename it is trying to open has replaced 'D' with '_' and the last digit is '1' not '0'.

How to make this script work?

Comment: I guess this is obvious, but here goes any way: problems like this are extra hard while we lack the ability to beam into your room and look at your files. Whatever you can do to give a reproducible example would help.

Comment: You're right, Nick. Next time I will as it's good practice. My excuse for this just this time: I managed to find a solution in the time I would've taken to think about how to make a reproducible example for this, and I assumed someone may have come across a similar issue based on just reading the (almost pseudo)script and outputs above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is less error prone to save the tempfile as an empty file to append to instead of using `capture` without handling the error code.

```
use "`pathb'fileb.dta", clear

levelsof pathb_variable, local(l)

tempfile append_file

preserve 
  clear
  save `append_file', emptyok
restore

foreach i of local l {
    capture confirm file "`patha'filea_`i'.dta"
    if _rc==0 {  
        append using `append_file'
        save `append_file', replace
    }
    
}
use `append_file', clear
```

Comment: It does no harm to put file names in `" "`. That doesn't appear to be the issue here.

Comment: `capture` is fine at doing what was intended but when it is catching an error you need to see what that error was with an `else di _rc`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out ````save `append_file', emptyok```` after initialising the tempfile made it work, so it was good to get confirmation from your answer. What does the `preserve`, `clear`, and `restore` around the saving of the empty tempfile do?

Comment: Good to know about the quotes, @NickCox. I added quotes to my code anyway: ````save `"`append_file'"', replace````

Comment: `preserve` saves a snapshot of the data that is restored after `restore`, such that anything you did in-between is dismissed. `clear` makes sure that nothing from "`pathb'fileb.dta" is included in the tempfile. This might not be what you need in this specific case, but often this is needed.